# Twitter Bootstrap accordion full height panes

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been troubling myself to achieve this with [twitter bootstrap accordion](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse):
[image: desired behavior]

Generally, using the accordion (bootstraps collapse plugin) is not a must.

**What I want to achieve** is to:

- use bootstrap as base framework,
- have fixed-top navbar,
- have full width/height content w/o scrollbars,
- have 3 separate, collapsible *content panes* (with always only one being expanded),
- have clicking on header part expand the *content pane* (and collapsing the previously expanded one),
- have scrolling occur only in the one expanded *content pane* (DIV 1|2|3 in pic),
- when *content panes* are collapsed, to have their overflow hidden,
- have each *content pane* have its configurable min-height (for its "header"),
- have this properly working for responsive layouts.

Would really love to get some help on this as I think I'm loosing my mind over this :(

The use of additional jQuery plugins (like jQuery UI) is "allowed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
 <div class="ui-accordion" id="accordion">        
    <h4 class="ui-accordion-header">DIV1</h4>
    <div class="ui-accordion-content" id="accordion-div1"></div>
    <h4 class="ui-accordion-header">DIV2</h4>
    <div class="ui-accordion-content" id="accordion-div2"></div>
    <h4 class="ui-accordion-header">DIV3</h4>
    <div class="ui-accordion-content" id="accordion-div3"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:
(nothing special)

JS:

```
$("#accordion").accordion( {
  heightStyle : "fill"
});
```

Comment: As clarification, this is referencing the jQuery UI plugin [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#fillspace) rather than Bootstrap [Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse), which may be a valid substitution, but won't have the same styling or use the data attributes Bootstrap users might expect.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve this with some JS:

```
var tabsHeight = $('.accordion-heading').outerHeight() * $('.accordion-heading').length;
var height = $('#your_accordion_container').innerHeight() - tabsHeight;

$('.accordion-inner').height(height - 1);
```

I haven't figured out why I need to do `- 1` yet but without it the `.accordion-inner` was too big.

Make sure to wrap this in a function and to call it every time the browser window gets resized. Also make sure that your `.accordion-inner` doesn't have any vertical padding or to remove that padding from the set height.

Comment: Will check it out and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone have a Bootstrap 3 solution for this?

Edit (this appears to work): https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2462

```
$('#accordion').collapse().height('auto');
```