# 100% height accordion "jump"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a 100% height accordion using the Twitter Bootstrap collapse component, exactly as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064809/twitter-bootstrap-accordion-full-height-panes).

I'm manually setting the heights of the `.accordion-inner` elements as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16545225/295813).

However I'm experiencing "bouncy" behaviour when expanding/collapsing the panels. I have removed all padding/margin/border from the `.accordion-inner` elements to eliminate that possibility.

It is most noticeable in IE10, however the problem is also evident in Chrome.

See this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/T47PZDmZhSjnaMMOh928?p=preview).

Any ideas what is causing this "jumpy" behaviour?

Comment: It works fine with chromium

Comment: I have checked in Chromium and the "bounce" at the bottom still exists.

Comment: Yeah, you are right didn't notice it.. But bad news is there are also a "bounce" in the boostrap docs : check it out http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. It's not as common so I didn't notice it, and thought it might be something to do with me trying to make it height 100%.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33697157/2208713 - I tried all the workaround answers given for this question and found this answer that actually worked in this other thread.  It boils down to not directly padding the expanding section (e.g. panel-body) but using a container div instead which has the padding

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Late to the party, but:

I had a similar problem, and noticed that if I removed a margin-top from the element below the collapsing one, and replaced it with padding-top, the transition was smooth.

So - check for margins on adjacent elements, and try replacing them with padding, if possible.

Comment: For me it was similar, but it was the margin around the .collapse div. I had a div with two classes: `.content` and `.collapse`. `.content` had margins. I separated the two classes into two separate divs, with `.collapse` wrapping `.content`

Answer (score 3):

I think the "jump" you're seeing is due to the CSS transitions for the .collapse class.

If you take a look at this SO thread [Turning off Twitter Bootstrap Navbar Transition animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119906/turning-off-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-transition-animation), you can see how to disable the transition with an overriding CSS class 'no-transition'. This doesn't stop the animation all together, but it speeds it up so that the jump is less noticeable...

Add `no-transition` to your accordion-body elements..

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in no-transition">
```

Add the CSS..

```
.no-transition {
  -webkit-transition: height 0.001s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.001s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.001s;
  -o-transition: height 0.001s;
  transition: height 0.001s;
}
```

Updated plunker..
http://plnkr.co/edit/xnvDGcDd21iCu69wKSub?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but ideally I would like to keep the animation (which I'm no longer seeing). Are you saying that you don't think this is possible?

Comment: You could try slowing down the animation by increasing the `s` on the transitions, but the either way I think the transitions are causing the "jump"

Comment: Removing the animation wiIl "fix" the issue in the same way turning off a warning of some sort will fix the issue the warning is warning about. I don't know how a 272k user replied with such an answer...

Comment: @alexandernst this was a suggestion for Bootstrap 2.x which hasn't been relevant in recent years. Thanks for taking the time to downvote my suggestion from 7 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<td><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#text1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#text1"</a>
<div class="collapse" id="text1" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-top:5px"><img src="..."></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .collapse.in{
    padding-bottom:5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this weird behavior where the accordion would expand to a much larger height than the actual visible content, and then collapse (jump) back to the actual visible content height.

Turns out that my accordion body for that panel had a few empty `html` elements, which, in my case were a few `divs` with `col-sm-4` class and nothing inside them. Once I commented them out this jumping behavior stopped. Hope this helps someone with similar problem.