# Bootstrap collapse animation not smooth

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
    <a for="collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="btn btn-primary">+ addInfo </a>
    <textarea class="form-control collapse" id="collapseOne" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <a for="collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="btn btn-info">+ subtitle </a>
    <input type="text" class="form-control collapse" id="collapseTwo">
</div>
```

The problem is when clicking the `addInfo` tab, you could find a jump in expanding the `text_area`, namely, the animation is not smooth.

Comment: It is, but once it gets to its min size of 1 line, the element is removes from screen.

Comment: Bootstrap alpha 4 answer here: you _need_ that `<div class="clearfix">` to wrap your nav or it gets janky.

Comment: @suzumakes the div with clearfix should wrap which nav? I see no nav on his code!

Comment: In my case was the align-items: center applied to the wrapper div the cause of the jerking

Answer (score 182, accepted):

In case anybody else comes across this problem, as I just have, the answer is to wrap the content which you want to collapse inside a `div` and collapse the wrapper div rather than the content itself.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">
    <a for="collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="btn btn-primary">+ addInfo</a>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <a for="collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="btn btn-info">+ subtitle</a>
    <input type="text" class="form-control collapse" id="collapseTwo">
</div>
```

Comment: Wrapping everything being collapsed inside a `div` also did it for my table!

Comment: thanks ! the fix is working, however, is there anyway to use it in a table with a 'tr' without having to wrap all the content in a div ?

Comment: I've never tried, but the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081737/1483190) suggests that a wrapper `div` might be required for each row. However, you could consider using jQuery's Wrap function (http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to automatically wrap each `<tr>` in a `<div>` with the appropriate class when the page loads.

Comment: Also fixed the problem of conflicting "d-lg-block" and "collapse"

Answer (score 113):

Jerking happens when the **parent div ".collapse"** has padding.

Padding goes on the child div, not the parent. jQuery is animating the height, not the padding.

**Example:**

```
  <div class="form-group">
       <a for="collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">+ addInfo</a>
       <div class="collapse" id="collapseOne" style="padding: 0;">
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" style="padding: 20px;"></textarea>
       </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <a for="collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">+ subtitle</a>
    <input type="text" class="form-control collapse" id="collapseTwo">
  </div>
```

[Fiddle Showing Both](http://jsfiddle.net/crrollyson/pxuxdwrh/)

Comment: great answer that works and a fiddle to boot that clearly demonstrates the solution working.  Kudos to the poster!

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks for explaining the role of the jquery.

Comment: Glad it helped √√ @RachelS

Comment: Or in my case it was height. Lesson here is to don't do any styling to collapse, wrap the content instead.

Comment: This should be mentioned in the document.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me out.

Comment: If your collapses are still jerking whilst following the above rule(s), then it's also worth noting that jerking can also occur if any surrounding elements (e.g. divs) have a margin set too. In such case, replace the margin with a padding for your surrounding elements.

Comment: I would add more than +1 if it would be possible :P

Comment: Had to remove `margin` from `p` element to resolve it. Thanks, your answer helped me nail it

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @CR Rollyson answer,

In case if you have a collapsible div which has a min-height attribute, it will also cause the jerking. Try removing that attribute from directly collapsible div. Use it in the child div of the collapsible div.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <a for="collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">+ Not Jerky</a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseOne" style="padding: 0;">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" style="padding: 20px;">No padding on animated element. Padding on child.</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugeshgupta000/uhjp14aq)

Comment: Yep, if min-height needs to be set for whatever reason, it should go on the textarea. Updated your fiddle version just to show it working smoothly for anyone checking it out: http://jsfiddle.net/uhjp14aq/3/

Answer (score 5):

I think there can be several situations that cause the jerking.  In my example, the issue deals with bottom margin on the non-animated child (even though the animated parent has no margin / padding).  When removing the margin, the animation becomes smooth.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <a for="collapseJerky" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseJerky" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseJerky">+ Jerky</a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseJerky" style="margin:0; padding: 0;">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">No margin or padding on animated element. Margin on child.</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseNotJerky" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseNotJerky">+ Not Jerky</a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseNotJerky" style="margin:0 padding: 0;">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" style="margin-bottom: 0;">No margin or padding on animated element or on child.</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    Moles and trolls, moles and trolls, work, work, work, work, work. We never see the light of day. This is just content below the "Not Jerky" to show that the animation is smooth.
</p>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1mvw9v2/16/)

Answer (score 5):

Padding around the collapsing div must be 0

Answer (score 4):

Although this has been answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28375912/5413283, and regarding padding it is not mentioned in the original answer but here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33697157/5413283.
i am just adding here for visual presentation and a cleaner code.

#### Tested on Bootstrap 4 ✓

Create a new parent div and add the bootstrap collapse. Remove the classes from the `textarea`

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseOne"> <!-- bootstrap class on parent -->
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
</div> <!-- // bootstrap class on parent -->
```

If you want to have spaces around, wrap `textarea` with **padding**. Do not add `margin`, it has the same issue.

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseOne"> <!-- bootstrap class on parent -->
    <div class="py-4"> <!-- padding for textarea -->
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div> <!-- // padding for textarea -->
</div> <!-- // bootstrap class on parent -->
```

#### Tested on Bootstrap 3 ✓

Same as bootstrap 4. Wrap the `textare` with `collapse` class.

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseOne"> <!-- bootstrap class on parent -->
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
</div> <!-- // bootstrap class on parent -->
```

And for `padding` **Bootstrap 3** does not have p-* classes like **Bootstrap 4** . So you need to create your own. Do not use `padding` it will not work, use `margin`.

```
#collapseOne textarea {
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mine got smoother not by wrapping each child but **wrapping whole markup with a helper div**. Like this:

```
<div class="accordeonBigWrapper">
    <div class="panel-group accordion partnersAccordeonWrapper" id="partnersAccordeon" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
         accordeon markup inside...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not set a height on the `.collapse` tag.  It affects the animation, if the height is overridden with css; it will not animate correctly.

Answer (score 3):

For others like me who had a different but similar issue where the animation was not occurring at all:

From what I could find it may be something in my browser setting which preferred less motion for accessibility purposes. I could not find any setting in my browser, but I was able to get the animation working by downloading a local copy of bootstrap and commenting out this section of the CSS file:

```
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .collapsing {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is pretty bad practice to override that. It is an accessibility issue and it is better to leave it as it is

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Bootstrap 5.0.2 for vue

I stumbeld upon this and it helped me to have a smooth animation:

I've just added this to my component`s css

```
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .collapsing {
    transition-property: height, visibility;
    transition-duration: 0.35s;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add version of bootstrap framework you used

Comment: tested with Bootstrap 4.6

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and noticed, I set height 100% to collapsing div element

```
<div>
  <button
    class="btn btn-primary"
    type="button"
    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
    data-bs-target="#collapseExample"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-controls="collapseExample"
  >
    Button with data-target
  </button>
     
  <div  never_put_height_in_this_element class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
 
  <div class="card card-body">
    <p>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
      terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer
      labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```