# Bootstrap 3 panel animation issue in safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari

I am using Bootstrap 3 panels

There is a weird animation going on when expanding a panel. It expands, collapses, and then reappears in the expanded state.

It happens only in Safari browser.

```
<main role="main">
       <h1 style="margin-top:63px;">Builds</h1>
<div class="panel-group mob_app_builds_history" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse25" role="tab" id="headingOne25">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse25" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse25">
          NBC <small style="mix-blend-mode: difference;">6 days ago</small>
        </a>
        <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse25" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading25">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p><b>Bundle:</b> abcd.ipa</p>
        <p><b>Tag:</b> "v3.17"</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div><div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zprL63tq/

Comment: Show us code. So, we can help.

Comment: It's working man. https://jsfiddle.net/zprL63tq/1/ in safari

Answer (score 0):

I added the following, it works fine.

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in no-transition">
Add the CSS..

.no-transition {
  -webkit-transition: height 0.001s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.001s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.001s;
  -o-transition: height 0.001s;
  transition: height 0.001s;
}
```

reference: [Twitter Bootstrap 100% height accordion "jump"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648020/twitter-bootstrap-100-height-accordion-jump)