# Bootstrap collapse accordion with full height panels (without JqueryUI)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

How can I use collapse panels with full heights?

[image]

Like this question: [Twitter Bootstrap accordion full height panes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064809/twitter-bootstrap-accordion-full-height-panes)
But without jquery UI and only with bootstrap?

I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/5xdp9prh/

```
$('#collapseTwo').collapse('show').height('auto');
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found this quick trick :

```
.collapse.in{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

The vh means view height, it also works with vw for for view width if you want an element to be as wide as the window.
One unit represents 1/100 of the size of the viewport you are using :)

Here is a working example.
https://jsfiddle.net/bebwgwj0/

Moreover this is supported by all modern browsers.