# How to stick accordin group on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to display CollaposibleGroups always on screen, at the moment my `Collapsible # 2` disappears when I expand `Collapsible # 1`

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Wc4xt/3670/

I want to add scroll bars to Collapsible Group Items.

I want to keep showing Collapsible Group Items headers on the screen always, so Collapsible Group Item #2 will always appear on the screen.

I will add window.resize later on as well, so I hope solution will work with that too. Thanks

Comment: you mean, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Wc4xt/3672/ ?

Comment: @Adam yes, but I want to display "Collapsible Group Item #2" on bottom of screen, even if I resize my window, thank you

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064809/twitter-bootstrap-accordion-full-height-panes ?

Comment: @Adam guy in that question wants views without scroll, but I want with scroll bars as its a list, let me see if I can use any of the answer in that question, but not sure if they will help me surely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

I added this CSS to make the accordion tab scrollable when it gets too long.

```
    .scroll-panel {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17981/